# Question about xSignals colors with Altium 20

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

Does anyone know why some of my nets are yellow even though they are the same length? I am using xSignals with Altuim 20 and on the documentation, it says that yellow means that they are short, but even double-checking they are the same size.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turnes out that I had my tolerance set to 0. Once I gave it an obtainable tolerance, it cleared up.